# "downcast from CLplacemark? to Clplacemark only unwraps optional"(swift2)

Tags: swift2, downcast, xcode7.2, clplacemark

how to fix this error :

```
"downcast from CLplacemark? to Clplacemark only unwraps optional"
```

so i use this code :

```
if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks.first as? CLPlacemark){}
```

and change placemarks[0] array but not work

and my code is :

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil {

       if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks[0] as? CLPlacemark){

            print(p)
            self.adsresslabel.text = "\(p.administrativeArea)\(p.postalCode)\(p.country)"
        }


    }else {
        print (error)
    }


    }
```

at this code :

```
if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks[0] as? CLPlacemark)
```

i have error about

```
 "downcast from CLplacemark? to Clplacemark only unwraps optional"
```

how to fix this error ?!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need to make a copy of the first placemark, you only need to do :

```
if let p = placemarks.first
{
        print(p)
        self.adsresslabel.text = "\(p.administrativeArea)\(p.postalCode)\(p.country)"
}
```

On the other hand, if you do need it to be a copy:

```
if let p0 = placemarks.first
{ 
        let p = CLPlacemark(placemark:p0)
        print(p)
        self.adsresslabel.text = "\(p.administrativeArea)\(p.postalCode)\(p.country)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The completion handler of `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler` is declared as

```
typealias CLGeocodeCompletionHandler = ([CLPlacemark]?, NSError?) -> Void
```

The placemarks are an optional array of `CLPlacemark` items therefore a down cast is not needed. You have only to check if the array is not `nil` and not empty as described in the answer of Alain T.